# Equivalence Relation question - $(a,b)S(c,d) \iff a-b=c-d$ such that $(a,b),(c,d) \in\ \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

The relation $(a,b)S(c,d) \iff a-b=c-d$ such that $(a,b),(c,d) \in \mathbb{N}  \times \mathbb{N}$

Need to find equivalent set for ($6,6)$ and $(2,5)$

I found for $[(6,6)] = \{(c,d) \in\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb N \mid c=d \}$

and for $[(2,5)] = \{(c,d) \in\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb N \mid c=d+3 \}$

I think I'm correct so far.. now I need to find the collection of equivalence classes $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} /S$

I found that the relation condition works when for example in $(2,5)$ its equivalence set all the difference between $5$ and $2$ that for every $c = d+3$ belongs, $(4,7), (10,13)$ i don't know how to put that perspective in mathematic words

Comment: did you mean $c=d\color{red}-3$ (or $d=c+3$)?

Comment: "such that $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N/S$" means?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri (a,b)/S such that a,b are natural numbers

Comment: @ShubhamJohri just check the definition for collections of all equivalence classes

Comment: I got it, you are talking about the quotient set.

Comment: In lay terms, the relation is that one pair of numbers is related to another pair of numbers if the difference between the first and second number in the former pair is the same as the difference between the first and second number in the latter pair.  The quotient set is then effectively sets of pairs corresponding to each of the different possible differences, which you have the positive differences like for $(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),\dots$ and the negative like for $(1,2),(1,3),\dots$.  It is worth pointing out that this is *precisely* how we often go about rigorously defining $\Bbb Z$...

Comment: @JMoravitz all the equivalence sets upon all natural numbers, so I need to represent this by Sigma notation I assume?

Comment: "Sigma notation" I can only imagine you are talking about summation symbol... no... there is only ever one thing added to one other thing at a time here.  The summation symbol is used when you want to sum many things together.

Comment: Use set builder notation... The quotient set will be $\{\{(a,b)\in \Bbb N\times \Bbb N~:~a-b=n\}~:~n\in\Bbb N\}\cup \{\{(a,a)\in\Bbb N\times \Bbb N~:~a\in \Bbb N\}\} \cup \{\{(a,b)\in \Bbb N\times \Bbb N~:~b-a=n\}~:~n\in\Bbb N\}$ ... that is... it is the set of all sets of all pairs of naturals such that the difference between the first and second is $n$ for each possible $n$, unioned with the set consisting of the set of all pairs such that the first and second entry are the same, unioned with the set of all sets of all pairs such that the difference between the second and first is $n$...

Comment: If you want representatives... if you allow $0$ as a natural number, then you have as natural choices of representatives $\dots,(0,3),(0,2),(0,1),(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),\dots$ which correspond to integers $\dots, -3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,\dots$ respectively.  If you don't allow $0$ then $\dots,(1,4),(1,3),(1,2),(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),\dots$ works just as well.  Part of the nuance here is that since this is how we are eventually *defining* $\Bbb Z$, we can't use $\Bbb Z$ to help us in defining it.

Comment: That said... the question as it is currently written technically then contains an error... it should have been written $(a,b)S(c,d)$ iff $a+d=b+c$ since we officially haven't defined subtraction before having defined the integers.

Comment: @JMoravitz can you say instead $ (a,b) \in\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \mid a-b=n : n \epsilon  \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: If you have defined the integers some other way before encountering this problem, then sure... however as stressed before, this is the quintessential standard approach taken to rigorously define the integers in the first place.  You may not use an object to define itself, that is circular and highly improper.

Comment: @JMoravitz for example what about this equivalent set for (2,10), which $n$ here is -8

Comment: At the time of encountering this problem for the first time following the usual course structure, "negative 8" is undefined, as is subtraction for that matter, it should have been a=b+n rather than a-b=n

Comment: @JMoravitz so what I gather is that the quotient set for any $(a,b)$ that are natural numbers, is    
 $\{ (d+(a-b), d) \}$ for any $d$ that belongs to natural numbers

Answer (score 1):

First, a given pair $(a,b)$ is equivalent to $(0,b-a)$ if $a\ge b$ and to $(a-b,0)$ if $a>b$, so the pairs with $a$ or $b$ zero form a full representative set.

The equivalence class of $(0,n)$ is $\{(a,a+n):a\in\Bbb N\}$, and similarly the equivalence class of $(n,0)$ is $\{(a+n,a):a\in\Bbb N\}$.

Note that this is the construction of the set of *integer* numbers $\Bbb Z$ based on the natural numbers, where a pair $(a,b)$ represents the difference $b-a$, so that $[(0,n)]$ represents the natural $n$ and $[(n,0)]$ represents the *negative* number $-n$ if $n>0$.

Comment: But I need to find all the equivalence sets upon all natural numbers, so I need to represent this by Sigma notation I assume?

Comment: If $\Bbb Z$ is already available for solving this, then you can write $\{\{(a,a+x):a\in\Bbb N,\ a+x\ge0\}\ :\ x\in\Bbb Z\}$ for the partition.